# BigQuery CLI show tableId only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, command-line-interface, bq

I want to get only the list of tables in a dataset. `bq ls dataset` command show the list of table name along with extra columns which are Type, Labels, Time, Partitioning and Clustered Fields.

How can I only show the `tableId` column?

[image]

Comment: I can't find in the doc a way to filter columns in the table output, but you can still use JSON format and filter columns with a tool like `jq` : `bq ls --format=json dataset | jq -r .[].tableReference.tableId`.

Answer (score 2):

```
bq ls <DATASET> | tail -n +3 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Working in Cloud Shell and locally on mac OS